# How to automatically add svn keyword anchors into the already present files

Tags: svn, keyword, revision

On a project version controlled by SVN, I see one can use Keyword Substitution in files in order to display important information about: who worked on it, the date it was changed, rev number, etc. just by adding relevant keyword anchors into my files. For this to work all one has to do is change the subversion config file

~/.subversion/config

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.php = svn:keywords=Id
*.js = svn:keywords=Id
```

So this would set the `$Id$` tag for all .php or .js files, and if I write `$Id$` keyword anchor anywhere in my files that keyword anchor will be replaced with the info I want.

Now this works only on ***New Files*** in the project, to circumvent this problem I can use (I havent yet for fear :P) this command at the root of my source tree:

```
find . \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec svn propset svn:keywords Id {} \;
```

Thats all good but now I would have to open and add the relevant keywords (in this case `$Id$`) to all my old files. Is there an easy way to perform this task because not only are there hundreds of files in the project, I dont want to open up a file and *edit* (meaning I would have to check in all these files, and the all important info of who changed it last and what revision it was changed in would be me with the latest revision, just because I added the keywords)?

Sorry for the long intro :P

Info I used:

http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-the-id-tag
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

No, **you can't edit** files **without editing** files

BTW, files will be modified in WC immediately after using propset

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, and saved me from inadvertedly modifying all the files in the project.